# Select from table only if all dynamic parameter values match

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following `animal` table:

```
id      | action
------------------
duck    | cuack
duck    | fly
duck    | swim    
pelican | fly
pelican | swim
```

I want to create a stored procedure and pass a group of values into a single parameter:

```
EXEC GuessAnimalName 'cuack,fly,swim'

Result:
duck
```

So, if it cuacks, it flyes and it swims then it's a duck. But also:

```
EXEC GuessAnimalName 'fly,swim'

Result:
pelican

---

EXEC GuessAnimalName 'fly'

Result:
No results
```

Parameter's number is dynamic.

**In order to guess the animal's name all actions provided must match or be found in `animal` table.**

This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @animal AS TABLE
(
    [id] nvarchar(8),
    [action] nvarchar(16)
)

INSERT INTO @animal VALUES('duck','cuack')
INSERT INTO @animal VALUES('duck','fly')
INSERT INTO @animal VALUES('duck','swim')
INSERT INTO @animal VALUES('pelican','fly')
INSERT INTO @animal VALUES('pelican','swim')

-- Parameter simulation
DECLARE @params AS TABLE
(
    [action] nvarchar(16)
)

INSERT INTO @params VALUES('cuack')
INSERT INTO @params VALUES('fly')
INSERT INTO @params VALUES('swim')

SELECT
    a.[id]
FROM
    @animal a
INNER JOIN
    @params p
ON
    a.[action] = p.[action]
GROUP BY
    a.[id]
HAVING COUNT(a.[action]) IN (SELECT COUNT([action]) FROM @animal GROUP BY [id])
```

Which gives the result:

```
Result:
--------
duck
--------
pelican
```

It should return just `duck`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert this to a stored proc  using `RANK`

```
declare @lookfor varchar(100) = 'swim,fly'

select id from 
(select 
id, rank() over (order by cnt desc)  rank_   -- get rank based on the number of match where should be the same number of rows
from
(
SELECT
    a.id, count(1) cnt   -- identify how many matches
FROM
    @animal a
INNER JOIN
    @params p
ON
    a.[action] = p.[action]
where charindex(p.action,@lookfor) > 0
group by a.id
having count(1) = (select count(1) from @animal x where a.id = x.id))  -- only get the animal with the same number of matches and rows
y)
z where rank_  = 1   -- display only with the most matches which should be the same number of rows matched
```

you don't need @params here

```
select id from 
(select 
id, rank() over (order by cnt desc)  rank_
from
(
SELECT
    a.id, count(1) cnt 
FROM
    @animal a
where charindex(a.action,@lookfor) > 0
group by a.id
having count(1) = (select count(1) from @animal x where a.id = x.id))
y)
z where rank_  = 1
```

Comment: If I pass `fly,swim` it returns `duck`. All parameters must match so it should return `pelican` .

Comment: After your edit it returns `duck` and `pelican` if I pass `fly,swim`.

Comment: yes.. should return both... if there is a cuack then should only be duck

Comment: `duck` should be discarded because `cuack` parameter was not provided, that's the requirement.

Comment: hmmm.. i might misunderstood your requirement. let me check again

Comment: try again... should give you what you want

Comment: It now displays `duck` and `pelican` for `cuack,swim,fly`.

Comment: someone fiddled the script. can you please try again from the solution above